# Delete a post based upon an id variable - different user sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session, sql-delete

**SOLVED**

I have a problem that has been tearing me apart for the last two weeks.
I want to be able to delete a post in my table based upon a given variable. Because of the different user content it's pretty difficult to delete a post that belongs to that certain user.

What I really want to know is how to get that certain ID from $rad on the admin.php to the delete query on perform_remove_time.php. Should I use GET or POST or any other method? I will have "input sanitize" with real_escape_string later on and I'm also aware of mysqli vs mysql. My code isn't pretty please bear with me.

From perform_remove_time.php

```
<?
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$time_id = ($_GET['time_id']);

$sql = "DELETE FROM time WHERE time_id = '$time_id' AND user_id = '$user_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result) {
    echo "<h3>Time deleted!</h3>";
    header("location:admin.php");
} else {
    echo "Something is wrong!";
}
?>
```

This is where the posts is fetched and displayed - admin.php

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$time_id = ($_GET['time_id']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM time WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ORDER BY time_id DESC"; 
$result = mysql_db_query("database","$sql") or die (mysql_error());

while ($rad=mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
?>
<?='Work session: '.$rad["time_id"]?>&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;Time on projekt: <?=$rad["hours"]?><a href="perform_remove_time.php?id=<? echo $rad['time_id']; ?>"> | Delete work session</a>
```

Also from admin.php further up on the page

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location:default.php");
    die();    
}
```

Comment: _Because of the different user content it's pretty difficult to delete a post that belongs to that certain user._ explain this.

Comment: When a user is logged in, only time entries belonging to that user is shown. I find it difficult to delete a specific post for a unique user. I'm able to erase every post for a user with an user_id, but it's the entry ID i want to be able to choose from a given variable. Hope i made myself clear, regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my observation, your delete link in 'admin.php' would not get  you to  'perform_remove_time.php' with the right GET parameter (time_id) for your delete code to work.

So i made a little modification to your delete link:

`<? echo "<a href='perform_remove_time.php?time_id=".$rad['time_id']."'> | Delete work session</a>"; ?>`

That modification would enable your delete link get to 'perform_remove_time.php' with the right GET parameter for it to work

---

**Update**

The code snippet from **perform_remove_time.php** looks fine to me, and would work as long as **$time_id** and **$user_id** contains valid values and also if your sql statement is correct. Now, from the code snippet you posted, I discovered that in **perform_remove_time.php**  **$time_id** would contain nothing because there was no **time_id** GET parameter in your delete link code `<a href="perform_remove_time.php?id=<? echo $rad['time_id']; ?>"> | Delete work session</a>`, the GET Parameter there is **id**, so I simply changed **id** to **time_id** to get things working.

new delete link code

`<? echo "<a href='perform_remove_time.php?time_id=".$rad['time_id']."'> | Delete work session</a>"; ?>`

Comment: Cheers alot! But on perform_delete page I need to have a GET? Because only with that modification it does not work. I'm quite of a beginner here but need this to work.

Comment: You're getting there, You seem to be right on track to achieve your goal, I have edited my answer and added a detailed explanation of my answer. Can you give a detailed list of errors you got ? be it php or sql

Comment: It works now!!!! It was $id = $_GET['rad']; that needed to be changed to $id = $_GET['time_id']; on remove page. Thank you so much, i have used your modified delete link code. I could not thank you enough. Cheers!